ubuntu 24.04 and php 7.4
I tried to install php 7.4 on ubuntu 24.04. I had to add this repostitory.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

But there is an error saying:
Unable to handle repository shortcut 'ppa/php/'

So I downloaded the key manually.
wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/ondrej-php.gpg

And added the repository manually.
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ondrej-php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu noble main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php.list

For the first time this worked. But there is still a warning.
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key 14AA40EC0831756756D7F66C4F4EA0AAE5267A6C uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)

Where can I get a proper key?
Is this repository deprecated?

https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1985

Read more about this issue on #1429 Packages are signed with RSA 1024 which is considered insecure.

Open the terminal and execute this:
gpgKey='B8DC7E53946656EFBCE4C1DD71DAEAAB4AD4CAB6'
gpgKeyPath='/etc/apt/keyrings/ondrej-ubuntu-php.gpg'
gpgURL="https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x${gpgKey}"
sudo curl "${gpgURL}" | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee ${gpgKeyPath} >/dev/null
gpg --dry-run --quiet --import --import-options import-show ${gpgKeyPath}


Edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-noble.sources to look like this:
Types: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/
Suites: noble
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/ondrej-ubuntu-php.gpg


Run sudo apt update


